# Storing methods identifiably in Java

Tags: java, methods, storage

I'm trying to come up with a solution to a problem where I want to store method references in some way so that I can invoke them when needed and remove them when I don't need them on my list of methods.

The underlying goal here goes something like this:

I have a Person class:

```
public class Person {
    private String ref, name;
    private String fatherRef; // can be reference string (such as "#1#") or a literal text (such as "the guy next door")

    public Person(String ref, String name) {
        this.ref = ref;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFatherRef() {return fatherRef;}

    public void setFatherRef(String ref) {
        fatherRef = ref;
    }

    ...
}
```

I make 2 instances of father and son and I set the father's ref as fatherRef for the son using **setFatherRef** method. I keep both of them on a list. Now say the father's object is deleted from the system and his ref becomes available for another person. To make sure the father is not referenced in the son's object after he's been deleted I came up with this:

I made an `interface IRefSetter {public void setRef(String ref);}` and I used it to make a `ArrayList<IRefSetter>` methods (such as `setFatherRef` or `setMotherRef`, etc.) and mapped that list using a father's ref onto a `HashMap<String,ArrayList<IRefSetter>>` so that anytime I'm getting rid of any person I can look at their ref and see if it's mapped to a list of methods that I can use to set their refs for all other `Person`s to null or "".

In this example the map would have only one mapping of father's ref to a list containing a single method referencing the `setFatherRef` from `Person` class. Now that would work fine but say I set the fatherRef to somebody else's ref and add the method reference for that new person the same way as with the original father. But now I'm left with a `HashMap` containing under the original father's ref a list on which I have a method stored to reset the son's fatherRef if the original father is deleted. But that's no longer necessary since the son now has a different father set with a different ref.

I can't see a simple way of being able to identify which method on my list is `son::setFatherRef` because the lambda function that's created each time I reference the method is different.

From that point I started looking into a very ugly kind of solution where instead of storing lambda functions matching my original `IRefSetter` interface I'm storing an `Object` reference to (in this case) son's `Person` instance and a method name as a `String` along with it and attempt to match the correct method to my `IRefSetter` interface by hand (using `Class` and `Method` classes). But that's a very ugly solution that instead of compiler errors would produce run-time errors which I don't like and the whole thing doesn't seem very OOP to me.

Am I missing a better solution here?

Comment: Have you considered using [`WeakReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) objects instead of string references?

Comment: How about a `Consumer<? super Person>`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WeakReference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better solution would be:

```
public class Person {
    private String ref, name;
    private Person father;
    private List<Person> children;

    ... a lot of obvious stuff here ...
}
```

Now when you remove a `Person`, you can look at that person's `father` and then remove the `Person` from the father's list of `children`, and also look at the removed person's `children` and set the `father` for each to null. If you want to know the father's ref just do `father.ref` or `getFather().getRef()`.

I sense that you don't want to do this for some reason, like it's dirty or not OOP or something like that. But this is the solution that best uses the capabilities of the language and runtime library.

Other solutions tend to just be more complicated ways of doing this. In your example, instead of having a `children` member, you have created a separate `HashMap` in which the key is the father ref and the value is an array of setter methods, but you see that this is just the same: for every child-father relationship, there is an entry in a list associated with the father.

If you insist on your setter strategy, a simple way to avoid the problem of accidentally clearing a `father` that no longer points to the person being removed would be to just check if the `father` field is still pointing to that person. The setter method would still be in the list and would still be called, but it wouldn't do any damage.

Comment: The thing with this approach is that I forgot to mention that ref String is a String for the reason it can also hold a literal text.

For example: Son's father can be: "#1#" (a reference string to a different Person) or "the guy next door"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this; if it's a `String` then it must hold text. Are you saying that sometimes the `ref` value doesn't refer to a `Person` in memory?

Comment: If the `fatherRef` field is set to "the guy next door," is there a `Person` with `ref` equal to "the guy next door"? How would you know when you'd removed "the guy next door?"

Comment: Elsewhere I store people in a ```HashMap<String,Person>``` where the person is stored like this: ```personStorage.put(person.getRef(), person)``` so it would look like this: ```personStorage.put("#1#", father)``` Looking at the son's fatherRef I can then decide if the String matches a ref I go and get the person from the personStorage and use his name otherwise I use the literal text in the fatherRef.

Comment: No, there is nobody with a ref "the guy next door". It's meant to be there so I don't have to create a new person each time the person with the name is mentioned somewhere and I don't know in advance if it's the same person. So I only store the text and don't have to store everything else that the Person would need to be.

Comment: That's right, you're going to have a `HashMap<String, Person>` in order to build this structure. First you load all the people you have into the map. Then you do a second pass through them and link the `father` and `children` references. If you don't find `fatherRef` in the map, then just leave the `father` field set to `null`.

Comment: Let's say you didn't want to store references in the `Person` object itself, you really want `String fatherRef` and that's it. Every time you remove a `Person`, just scan through `personStorage` and clear out any `fatherRef` fields that point to the person you removed. You're going to say, well, that's slow. You want to keep track of which people have some particular `fatherRef` so you can clear them later. But that's the `children` field that I have suggested.

Comment: You could externalize it as `HashMap<String, List<Person>> children`, and the given a `Person` you could find its father via lookup of `fatherRef` in `personStorage` and its children via lookup of `ref` in `children`.

Comment: That's probably better but doing it the way would force me to make such maps for every role (and there are more than father and mother roles connecting other people to a person), right? So in turn I would change the solution from going through a buch of specific methods (lambda methods) to going through a buch of specific maps.

Comment: Either way I like the direction of this approach much better. I don't want to be forced to bend the system to the deal with methods on the low level and ignoring OOP in the process.

Comment: I think that you'll find that all well-performing solutions look the same, differing only in where you decide to park the `Person` references you need to make it work. Looking up `Person` references by `ref` value in `personStorage` is a space-time tradeoff; you avoid storing an extra `father` reference in `Person` but you incur the cost of the lookup. A good question to ask yourself is, do you want to be as fast as possible, or are you more interested in saving memory?

Comment: Things would have been much easier if ```son::setFatherRef == son::setFatherRef``` would be true.